# passing a variable to JS in shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny

Below is the sample action button with JS in it.This is hard coded. But actually,
the 'small_ID' below is very dynamic and will get changed. So how can i pass a variable inside document.getElementById ? Can anyone  help?

```
actionButton("show1",class = "act_button", list(span(id = "m1", class="top left", "Model 1"), span(class="top right", Sys.time())),
                         onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('btnid', document.getElementById('small_ID').textContent);")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [`paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/paste):

```r
actionButton(
    "show1",
    class = "act_button", 
    list(
        span(id = "m1", class="top left", "Model 1"), 
        span(class="top right", Sys.time())
    ),
    onclick = paste(
       "Shiny.setInputValue('btnid', document.getElementById('",
       small_ID,
       "').textContent);",
       sep=""
    )
)
```

...where `small_ID` should be your variable holding the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert variables into strings using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
actionButton("show1", class = "act_button", 
  list(
    span(id = "m1", class="top left", "Model 1"), 
    span(class="top right", Sys.time())
  ),
  onclick = `Shiny.setInputValue(
    'btnid', document.getElementById('${dynamicId}').textContent);
  `)
```

Comment: Thanks.. can I use paste inside like ````document.getElementById('${paste0("t",dynamicId)}')````

Comment: I don't know what `paste` is, but you can place any javascript within the embedded placeholder: `${ ... }`